# problems in migrating 32bit application on 64 bit

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to migrate existing c++ 32 code to 64 code on windows7 with visual studio 2010.i never did 64bit compilation before. with the help of internet references i did the setup for 64 bit compilation. like VS2010 with 64 bit compiler etc and other configuration changes.
In the preprocessor i removed WIN32 and added WIN64. i have some other pre-processors like OS_WIN_32 and some other which are specific in my code.
In the code wherever WIN32 was getting used i added extra condition as || WIN64 this is just to ensure that application should get compiled with win32 as well as win64.
When i am trying to compile the code i am getting the compilation error saying

fatal error C1189: #error :  Only one of the WIN32 and WIN64 symbols should be defined

this error is coming from the local code where we have a check whether both WIN32 and WIN64 are defined. that code is as shown below.

```
#if defined WIN32 && defined WIN64
# error Only one of the WIN32 and WIN64 symbols should be defined
#endif
```

in VS2010 if macros are not enabled then the code inside the macro gets greyed out. in my code also the above error is greyed out. but still i am getting that error.

The code where i added WIN64 is including windows.h. for reference givine it below.

```
#if defined WIN32 || defined WIN64
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#endif
```

So my question is why i am getting this error? shouldnt we add windows.h for 64bit compilation.? i tried by commenting this inclusion but i am getting other errors wrt HANDLE which are used in the code.
If i go to WIN32 definition VS2010 is pointing to a definition in windef.h file. This file is present in Microsoft SDKs\windows\v7.0A\include folder i.e. not my local code. 
for referance that definition is given below.

```
#ifndef WIN32
#define WIN32
#endif
```

So i want to know why compiler is getting both pre-processors WIN32 and WIN64.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try look "Lessons on development of 64-bit C/C++ applications" - http://www.viva64.com/en/l/ and "Using _WIN64/WIN64 macros" - http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0040/

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't define either yourself. The macro's that should be used to check this are

```
_WIN32 // always defined for Windows apps
_WIN64 // only defined for x64 compilation
```

These are defined by the compiler (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Often, the IDE adds the unprefixed macros to the commandline to not let legacy projects which use the non-documented unprefixed versions fail to build. The fact that they work is not a reason to use them, when documented alternatives are present.

---

It boils down to this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  // We're on Windows, yay!
#ifdef _WIN64
  // We're on x64! Yay!
#else // _WIN64
  // We're on x86 (or perhaps IA64, but that one doesn't matter anymore). Yay!
#endif // _WIN64
#else // _WIN32
  // We're not on Windows, maybe WindowsCE or WindowsPhone stuff, otherwise some other platform
 #endif
```

Comment: i am not sure whether i understand your explanation or not. but i did not added _WIN64. i added WIN64 since existing code was using WIN32 (both are without underscore) even the WIN32 definition in windef.h file is also from Microsoft SDKs. 
If i misunderstood your explanation can you please explain in detail. Sorry for inconvenience. Thanks

Comment: yeh after reading tour initial answer i edited the code as shown below
    #if defined _WIN32 && defined _WIN64
    #error Only one of the WIN32 and WIN64 symbols should be defined
    #endif

still i got the same error. also one more query after seeing your edited response is x64 code will always have _WIN32 and _WIN64 defined. is this understanding correct? if yes then having the code to throw error when both are defined is not the correct coding. is this right?

Comment: in fact the code which is throwing error is from 3rd party library (ospace from recursion software) i am not sure why they dnt checked _WIN32.